# regex: everything between (#) and (? or & or \n)

Tags: regex

Need to capture

> https://my-stite.com/sec/pics/page.html#home
>
> https://my-stite.com/sec/pics/page.html#manage
>
> https://my-stite.com/sec/pics/page.html#proc-PO&/editProc/
>
> https://my-stite.com/sec/pics/page.html#proc-PO?/abcse

Result should be

```
home
manage
proc-PO
proc-PO
```

Tried (.*)(?<=#)(.*?)(?=\n|\?|\&)(.*|\n) but it does not capture new line

Comment: If you want to parse URL, it's better to use URL parser (available in most modern langs).

Comment: What you sometimes see it the part in the fragment (everything after the `#`) is formatted like a query string; your patterns seems similar, so first parsing the URL, taking the fragment of it, then getting the 'path' part from it (everything before `?` or `&`) and parsing everything after the first `?` or `&` as a query string should work quite well and you'll be able to use standard components/classes for these tasks. (the URL class in javascript for instance)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex pattern:

```
(?<=#).*?(?=(?:[?&\n]|$))
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the pattern:

```
(?<=#)            assert that a pound sign immediately preceeds
.*?               then match everything until
(?=(?:[?&\n]|$))  seeing either ?, &, \n OR the end of the input
```

Note the subtle inclusion of checking for the end of the input as a stopping condition.  This covers the situation where a URL like the following happens to be the last URL in the input:

```
https://my-stite.com/sec/pics/page.html#manage
```

In this case, neither `?`, `&`, nor `\n` would match, but we still want to capture the text `manage`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#\K[^?&\n]+
```

[Here Is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/A3C5Hz/2)

Comment: Perhaps replace `+` with `*`?

Comment: also, `?` and `&` don't need quoting inside `[]`

Comment: @JonasBerlin. I used `+` for not empty. The `?&` are in `[]` because this can be OR this Or this.

Comment: `[^?&\n]` is same as `[^\?\&\n]`. `?` and `&` are not special characters inside `[]` and therefore don't need quoting.

Answer (score 1):

Just to put my two cents in:

```
#([^/\s&?]+)
```

Grab the first group and see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/O6iHL9/2/).